# Async await not fire in the project, but works fine in Xcode playground

Tags: swift, async-await

The following code piece works in Xcode playground, but not working if I put into `.onAppear/.task` in a project.

Appreciate if anyone could help me on it.

```swift
let n = Notification.Name("event")
Task {
    for await value in NotificationCenter.default.notifications(named: n, object: nil) {
        if let str = value.object as? String {
            await asyncPrint(value: str)
        }
    }
}

NotificationCenter.default.post(name: n, object: "event1")
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: n, object: "event2")
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: n, object: "event3")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create your notifications stream outside of the `Task`, and before you `post`, it eliminates this timing issue:

```swift
let n = Notification.Name("event")
let notifications = NotificationCenter.default.notifications(named: n, object: nil)

Task {
    for await notification in notifications {
        if let string = notification.object as? String {
            await asyncPrint(value: string)
        }
    }
}

NotificationCenter.default.post(name: n, object: "event1")
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: n, object: "event2")
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: n, object: "event3")
```

Comment: Obvious credit due to Rob Napier for pointing why it failed (+1).

Answer (score 2):

Your notifications are going to be posted before the observation is added. There is no queue of previous notifications. If nothing is waiting on the notification, it is discarded.

The likely order for your code is:

- Create `n`
- post, post, post (no observers, so they're discarded)
- Then the Task starts and begins waiting. No notifications ever show up.

This can work in a playground because playgrounds evaluate things in unusual orders, and may evaluate various lines more than once. It is extremely difficult to use playgrounds to explore async code because you don't know what order things will be evaluated in.